# cakePHP meioupload, upload image to a different folder for each model

Tags: cakephp, image-upload, meio-upload

I use meioupload to upload images in cakePHP, i use a table called 'attachment' to save the uploaded image's information, this is the structure of my attachment table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `attachments` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `foreign_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dir` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `mimetype` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `filesize` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `width` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And i currently have another 2 tables connected with this through the class field (table name) and foreign_id. Now my question is, how can i save the uploaded image to a different folder for each model?

For example: i would like to save my post's image into 'post' folder and to save my profile image into 'profile' folder

**UPDATE:** in my attachment model

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'MeioUpload' => array(
        'filename' => array(
            'dir' => 'post', #i set the default folder as 'post' at the moment
            'create_directory' => true,
            'allowed_mime' => array(
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png'
            ),
            'allowed_ext' => array(
                '.jpg',
                '.jpeg',
                '.png'
            ),
            'thumbsizes' => array(                  
                'large' => array(
                    'width' => 500,
                    'height' => 500
                ),
                'small' => array(
                    'width' => 100,
                    'height' => 100
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

**UPDATE #2** : let say that i currently have 3 tables, "attachment" "post" and "profile", the one that actAs meioupload is "attachment", every time i upload an image through "post" or "profile", i will save the image information into "attachment", foreign_id and class fields in "attachment" is the one connecting "attachment" to "post" and "profile".

UPDATE #3 : i followed Dunhamzzz suggestion on using the behavior on the fly, and come up with this solution, and it works.

```
$this->Attachment->Behaviors->attach(
    'MeioUpload', array(
        'filename' => array(
            'dir' => 'avatars'
        )
    ));
```

Thanks

Comment: pls post your $actAs code from your models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your MeioUpload, specifically the 'dir' option, you can put `{ModelName}` or `{fieldName}` in to alter where the file saves. Here is the default in the behaviour itself:

`dir' => 'uploads{DS}{ModelName}{DS}{fieldName}',`

**Update**

In order to get MeioUpload to support different settings for the same model, you could try [attaching the behaviour on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1072/Using-Behaviors), which allows you to change the settings as you please.

eg in your posts action

```
$this->Attachment->Behaviours->attach('MeioUpload', array('dir' => '/uploads/posts/');
```

Be sure to read the part on behaviours on the docs, it will hopefully help you work out a solution on a per-action basis as opposed to per-model which comes with behaviours.

Comment: hmm that is not what i mean, if i do {ModelName}, it will only upload the images into "attachment" folder, since the one that actAs this behavior is "attachment" model, i will update my question then.

Comment: @dunhamzz where should attach that? i try using it inside my controller, and it doesnt work

Comment: I guess attach it in a controller action instead of in the $actsAs, just make sure you pass all settings to it when you attach it.

Comment: oohh it's a typo, it should be "behaviors" instead of "behaviours" i think thats why i got the error message, i am gonna try again, and i'll let you know. thanks

Comment: it works, i need several modification tho, thanks to have pointing me out about this

Comment: Haha British that's the British spelling!

Comment: ahaha i didn't about that, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for the $actAs array.

```
    'MeioUpload' => array(
        'filename' => array(
            'dir' => 'files/banners',
            'create_directory' => false,
            'allowed_mime' => array(
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/gif',
                'image/png'
            ),
            'allowed_ext' => array(
                '.jpg',
                '.jpeg',
                '.png',
                '.gif'
            ),
        )
    ),
```

as you can see, there is a key "dir" that you can modify